# How do I restore grub on a uefi boot after a windows update wiped it?

Tags: debian, windows, grub2, uefi

Until yesterday I had a dual boot debian / win8 with grub that worked like a charm. Yesterday a stupid windows update totally wiped grub and I'm now unable to boot in linux.
I installed linux a year ago and I remember it was quite a pain to properly make grub work and I don't even remember all the steps involved.

What is the correct procedure to restore it?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix the boot again and here are the steps. I'm aware there's a tool called `bcdedit` but, for some reasons, it doesn't work. It always returns me a "parameter is incorrect" error (I ran the cmd.exe as Administrator , either in normal and safe mode).
I'm also assuming Secure Boot is turned off in the Bios.

**From Windows**

- open `cmd.exe` as Administrator and lunch the command `vmount s: /s`
- go to `s:` and navigate the directories until you find where the `grubx64.efi` is located. Mine was under `s:\EFI\debian\`.
- go to `s:\EFI\Microsoft\boot` and create a backup of the `bootmgfw.efi` file and then overwrite it with the `grubx64.efi`.
- reboot. Now you should be able to reach the grub menu and boot to Linux but you'll be unable to boot to Windows. Boot to Linux then.

**From Linux**

- open a shell and go to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot` and restore the previously backed up `bootmgfw.efi`.
- run `grub-install` (it may require root privilege - sudo)
- run `update-grub2` (it may require root privilege - sudo)